# create container from specific value if exists otherwise from default

Tags: c++

I have a static const vector of some predefined values and I want to create a new one (may be pointer/ref) which will contain a custom values (from somewhere) if they exist or the values from predefined one. Moreover I really don't want to copy the values from predefined to a new one.

The following code (with errors) more or less describes the situation:

```
static const std::vector<int> defvals = { 1, 2, 3, ... };
const std::vector<int>& real = defvals;

std::vector<int> custom;
if (hasCustom) {
   custom.push_back(1); ...
}
real = custom; // **not possible**
....
for (int val : real) {
   // do smth
}
```

Comment: maybe a macro would help

Comment: @JSelser No, a macro wouldn't help.

Comment: I don't understand this code.

Comment: Brian, what exactly you do not understand?

Comment: @Brian What exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C.2B.2B), you just have to declare `real` after you populate `custom`.

```
static const std::vector<int> defvals = { 1, 2, 3, ... };

std::vector<int> custom;
if (hasCustom) {
    custom.push_back(1); ...
}

// Get a reference to the correct vector.
const std::vector<int>& real = hasCustom ? custom : defvals;

for (int val : real) {
    // do smth
}
```

Comment: Cool, I completely forget about ternary operator. Thanks a lot!